# There's a new Telegram "button" for websites - need help to use it on blogspot

Tags: button, telegram, blogger

I'm trying to implement this button for my blog (on Blogger) but I can't really understand how it works, take a look at this post (you will see the Telegram Button with the type "Forward" at the end of the post): https://telegram.org/blog/supergroups

I found the HTML, this is the markup:

```
<a href="https://telegram.me/share/url?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftelegram.org%2Fblog%2Fsupergroups&amp;text=Group%20Admins%2C%20Supergroups%20for%20up%20to%201000%20members%2C%20new%20In-App%20Notifications%20and%20Quick%20Share." class="tl_telegram_share_btn" id="tl_telegram_share_btn" data-text="Group Admins, Supergroups for up to 1000 members, new In-App Notifications and Quick Share." data-url="https://telegram.org/blog/supergroups"><i class="tl_telegram_share_icon"></i><span class="tl_telegram_share_label" target="_blank">Forward</span></a>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
.tl_telegram_share_btn {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #54a9eb;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 5px 12px 5px 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
i.tl_telegram_share_icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background: url(/img/share_logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 22px 22px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
    .tl_telegram_share_label {
    line-height: 21px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    /* margin-top: 1px; */
}
```

Despite the CSS, seems that the tricky part resides on the HTML markup, I understand that under blogspot there are some html tags and parameters to use, as:

```
  data:post.canonicalUrl
  data:post.title
```

I was trying to do it, using data:post.canonicalUrl in "data-url", and inside the href value, but nothing works.

Comment: sorry I'm realtively new to this :/ what do you mean with superuser? is a section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Blogspot use this code:

```
<a expr:href='&quot;https://telegram.me/share/url?url=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;text=&quot; + data:post.title'>Share on Telegram</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a Telegram function, where you call the url, it returns a deep-linked URI for apps to open certain action. For this case, you're sharing the link, so it's `"/share/url?url=..."`.

To use the button, you can either put CSS to your blog(if blogspot/Blogger allows), then add CSS class to the "Forward" button:

```
<a href="//telegram.me/share/url?url=myURL&amp;text=myTEXT" class="tl_telegram_share_btn">
  <i class="tl_telegram_share_icon"></i>
  <span class="tl_telegram_share_label">Forward</span>
</a>
```

Or, you can place a picture for the link itself:

```
<a href="//telegram.me/share/url?url=myURL&amp;text=myTEXT" class="tl_telegram_share_btn">
  <img src="/path/to/mybtn.png" class="tl_telegram_share_img" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply Insert this code and add some CSS according to your Other share icons

```
<a class='telegram' expr:href='&quot;https://telegram.me/share/url?url=&quot; + data:post.title + &quot;%20%2D%20&quot; + data:post.url' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'/>
```

Example CSS using font awesome icons

```
.telegram{background:#2DA5D9}.telegram:before{font-family:FontAwesome;content:&quot;\f2c6&quot}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are your URL options for telegram.me.

```
https://t.me/share/url?url={url}&text={text}
https://telegram.me/share/url?url={url}&text={text}
tg://msg_url?url={url}&text={text}
```

**The official API documentation source: [Core.Telegram.org: Widgets -> Sharing Button](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/share#custom-buttons)**

They suggest the `t.me` format, not telegram.me.  You may share:

- `url` : The URL you want to share.
- `text` : Text to accompany the URL you want to share.

If you are interested in watching a project that keeps track of these URLs, then check us out!: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#telegramme

[image: Social Share URLs]

Comment: thank you so much, really interested on this project! (This question was made on  4 years ago, when they did not have that documentation for their api)